# How are the users deleted from stackoverflow after they request for it?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

There are about [39 users (according to Google)](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22User+Please+delete+me%22&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+%22User+Please+delete+me%22) and [60 on stackexchange](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackexchange.com+%22User+Please+delete+me%22&oq=site:stackexchange.com+%22User+Please+delete+me%22) who want their accounts to be deleted.

How are these users deleted? Is there any threshold after which they are automatically removed?

Comment: why the -1? Care to explain?

Comment: Maybe because, judging from the sole answer on your question, it's unclear what you're asking?  The admins chant an incantation and sprinkle magic pixie dust over the servers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're not supposed to tell people that. That's privileged information!

Comment: that could be name ... http://math.stackexchange.com/users/7044/please-delete-me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How are these users deleted?

Manually once they notify us.

There are some pitfalls to the process. Most of them come down to communication issues. For example, what some people do is email us from an unrelated and/or mistyped email without linking to their account, so we have no idea who they are and can't respond to them. Or they have several profiles they'd like to remove, but they don't mention that when contacting us. Those accounts will probably languish forever.

Some emails used to get trapped in the spam folder never to be seen again. (We get an impressive amount of spam every day.) Using the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page should theoretically fix this specific issue, but some folks still email us directly. Spam-trapping is rare, but I figured I'd mention it for the sake of completeness.

Our typical response time is a couple of days, so if someone doesn't hear from us in a few days, they can ping us again to see what's what.

As an aside, we do automatically delete *some* abandoned accounts. The specific rules for that are described [in this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/).

Answer (score 1):

Those are users that probably wanted to get deleted using [the old method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7979/5) (Note: the new method is to use the 'Delete my user profile' request via '[contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)').

**AND:**

a) Forgot to flag something or email them to complete the request, or
b) First flagged or emailed them *before* adding the 'please delete me' on their profiles.

Comment: I am not very sure about that. Since I wanted to delete my account of money.stackexchange. And it was not really deleted after 2 months and after that, I changed my mind to keep the account. I followed all the steps mentioned in the "contact us"

Comment: @zengr Your email may have been eaten by Google's spam filter. The "contact us" form is (in theory) not susceptible to that.